# How much electricity can be generated from stove's heat?

Tags: power-electronics, energy, peltier

Yesterday I asked a whether it is profitable to put a thermoelectric generator (TEG) between a stove and a freezer regarding electricity terms. I was missing a point, which was that heat was being dumped from stove to the freezer due to which the freezer would require even more energy to work.

What if we don't dump heat to the freezer?

For instance let's put a styrofoam block which directly came out from the freezer and place it below the other part of the TEG where heat would be dumped and the other part remains hot due to the stove.

Average households use a stove for cooking for about 1.5 hours to 2.5 hours at maximum and styrofoam can maintain its temperature for longer after cooking you can keep the styrofoam block out for a while to cool down a bit or run it in cold water and then keep it back in the freezer.

So this can create electricity but how much power can it generate approximately?

Comment: It makes no difference whether you use the freezer to directly cool the TEG, or if you first cool an object inside the freezer and then use that to cool the TEG instead. The freezer still has to do exactly the same job, requiring energy.

Comment: If you are cooling the block in the freezer, then where does the energy to drive the freezer come from? Check out laws of thermodynamics 1 & 2.

Comment: Why put it between a stove and freezer? If you wanted to generate electricity from the waste heat you could put the TEG between the heat source and a heat sink that's cooled by the room air. This could be done with the freezer condenser coil as well, as it just dumps the heat removed from the inside of the freezer into the room. It would require no extra power as the excess heat from the stove and freezer is just going into the air anyway. I'm not saying it's going to be very efficient, but it would harvest some of the normally wasted energy.

Answer (score 9):

No it is not profitable and cannot even theoretically be profitable. A real TEG will be more than an order of magnitude worse than break-even. The temperature difference is created by a heater and the fridge compressor, which both cost energy to operate, more than you can can possibly get back no matter how clever the approach. Real TEGs have miserable efficiency. Recall Ginsberg's theorem:

0. There is a game (consequence of zeroth law of thermodynamics)
1. You can't win. (consequence of first law of thermodynamics)
2. You can't break even. (consequence of second law of thermodynamics)
3. You can't even get out of the game. (consequence of third law of thermodynamics)

If you can find a source of "free" or inexpensive temperature difference such as geothermal or deep lake or ocean water it might be profitable. At the expense of causing some changes to the environment. The temperature difference has to persist while heat is flowing. This an issue with geothermal, for example, extracting heat cools the rock and reduces the temperature difference.

Answer (score 2):

"High-efficiency" thermoelectric generators have about 5% efficiency. Maybe more if I'm not up to date, but it's pretty low. This means if you manage to extract one kilowatt of heat from your stove, you'll get 50 watts of electricity. Problem is, you have to get rid of the kilowatt of heat on the other side, and that will require a large heat sink (therefore expensive) or a smaller heat sink with a fan... which will consume all the power. In fact, one stove-related application of TEGs is to run a fan to heat the room better. But you'll never get an amount of electricity that is worth the price.

If you intend to send a space probe to somewhere the sun doesn't shine very much, like Saturn, and you got the budget for a few pounds of plutonium to generate the heat, then that's fine. It makes a nice million dollar battery that lasts for years.

On Earth, it is used in very low power applications where the low efficiency is not important. For example there are wristwatches powered by TEGs, but in this case, the watch only needs a few microwatts, so that's fine.

Now about the styrofoam block, you're confusing insulation and heat capacity. Styrofoam is a good insulator and has very low heat capacity, so it would be useless for absorbing heat.

If you want "free" off-grid electricity, the cheapest and lowest maintenance solution is solar panels.

If you want to optimize the energy use of the stove, to use much less fuel, and it uses wood/coal, then get or make a rocket stove instead.

Answer (score 0):

The pure answer to the title question is given by the Carnot theorem; it depends on the thermal gradient between the stove temperature and the cold source (air or cold water, or for best overall energy use, the cool return of the central heating loop, pre-heating it before the boiler (US : furnace).

I'll not repeat the Carnot theorem here, it's easily found.

The question in the body is : how close to Carnot can a TEG get? Unfortunately, nowhere close with current material technology. You'd need a conductor between hot and cold junctions with very good electrical conductivity, and very poor thermal conductivity. And these (today) simply don't exist.

Can you approach Carnot more closely with something other than TEG?

Maybe ... the best candidate, despite being thermomechanical, is probably a Stirling engine. I recommend searching for Hargreaves work ["The Philips Stirling Engine"](http://Hargreaves%20The%20Philips%20Stirling%20Engine), and online sources or books by [Allan Organ](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Stirling-Cycle-Engines-Workings-Design-ebook/dp/B00GQWOHFK/ref=sr_1_1?crid=99GNT84GWDMG&keywords=Allan%20Organ&qid=1644588348&s=books&sprefix=allan%20organ%2Cstripbooks%2C154&sr=1-1) (also [Organ and Finkelstein](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Air-Engines-History-Science-Reality/dp/0791801713/ref=sr_1_2?crid=149Y8NMT0JFOT&keywords=Organ%20and%20Finkelstein&qid=1644588478&s=books&sprefix=organ%20and%20finkelstein%2Cstripbooks%2C147&sr=1-2)) for the state of the art there. But it's not trivial and despite some successes, many more have tried and failed.